# error: incomplete type 'typename' named in nested name specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I try to define my own `boost::intrusive::slist`.
In addition, I want to have another static method in the class. (`copy_buffer_from_list`) which gets list& and iterator& as parameters.
The problem is some definitions are circular and I can't get it right.
Here is the current code :

```
#include <boost/intrusive/slist.hpp>

typedef boost::intrusive::slist_base_hook<> InputBufferSglHook;

class InputBufferSglNode;

// list
typedef boost::intrusive::slist<InputBufferSglNode, boost::intrusive::cache_last<true>> InputBufferSglList;
typedef InputBufferSglList::iterator InputBufferSglIterator;

class InputBufferSglNode : public InputBufferSglHook
{
public :

    InputBufferSglNode(const void* buffer, size_t size); 

    ~InputBufferSglNode() {};

    // copy 'size_t' bytes from list to target, if list doesn't have enough space, method shall return false
    static bool copy_buffer_from_list(InputBufferSglList &list, InputBufferSglIterator &iter, size_t &offset_in_node, const InputBufferSglIterator& end, uint8_t *target, size_t size);

    void reset();

public:
    const void *m_buffer;
    size_t m_size;
};

// empty list
const InputBufferSglList s_EMPTY_INPUT_BUFF_SGL = InputBufferSglList();

InputBufferSglNode::InputBufferSglNode(const void* buffer, size_t size) :
    InputBufferSglHook(),
    m_buffer(buffer),
    m_size(size)
{
    // empty
}

void InputBufferSglNode::reset()
{
    m_buffer = nullptr;
    m_size = 0;
}

static bool InputBufferSglNode::copy_buffer_from_list(InputBufferSglList &list, InputBufferSglIterator &iter, size_t &offset_in_node, const InputBufferSglIterator& end, uint8_t *target, size_t size)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Notice I tried to forward declare `InputBufferSglNode` but I get the following error while compiling :

```
error: incomplete type 'InputBufferSglNode' named in nested name specifier
note: in instantiation of template class 'boost::intrusive::slist<InputBufferSglNode, boost::intrusive::cache_last<true>, void, void, void, void>' requested here
typedef InputBufferSglList::iterator InputBufferSglIterator;
        ^
note: forward declaration of 'InputBufferSglNode'
class InputBufferSglNode;
      ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type is incomplete, like it says. This is not legal (intrusive containers need to know the implementation details - bases, size etc. - at instantiation time).

The documentation specifically mentions that you should avoid deducing hook types when you do this kind of 'nested' use.

Given this, there are several ways to fix it:

1. You could just shuffle things around: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d32fc155b70a8889)**.
2. If you really would like `InputBufferSglList` to be a global typedef, of course, you can just alias it: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0f70d45810bc94e)**
3. **UPDATE** To the comment, it seems you're really insisting on making this a forward-declared list type, and you can, as described here [in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/intrusive/recursive.html):

   ```
   typedef boost::intrusive::slist_base_hook<> InputBufferSglHook;
   class InputBufferSglNode;

   // list
   typedef boost::intrusive::slist<
           InputBufferSglNode,
           boost::intrusive::base_hook<InputBufferSglHook>,
           boost::intrusive::cache_last<true> 
       > InputBufferSglList;

   typedef InputBufferSglList::iterator InputBufferSglIterator;
   ```

   Job Done. See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e4b79fa1acef65e)** too.

#### Full Demo

The third version in full, for future reference:

```
#include <boost/intrusive/slist.hpp>

typedef boost::intrusive::slist_base_hook<> InputBufferSglHook;
class InputBufferSglNode;

// list
typedef boost::intrusive::slist<
        InputBufferSglNode,
        boost::intrusive::base_hook<InputBufferSglHook>,
        boost::intrusive::cache_last<true> 
    > InputBufferSglList;

typedef InputBufferSglList::iterator InputBufferSglIterator;

class InputBufferSglNode : public InputBufferSglHook
{
  public:

    InputBufferSglNode(const void* buffer, size_t size); 

    ~InputBufferSglNode() {};

    // copy 'size_t' bytes from list to target, if list doesn't have enough space, method shall return false
    static bool copy_buffer_from_list(InputBufferSglList &list, InputBufferSglIterator &iter, size_t &offset_in_node, const InputBufferSglIterator& end, uint8_t *target, size_t size);

    void reset();

  public:
    const void *m_buffer;
    size_t m_size;
};

// empty list
const InputBufferSglList s_EMPTY_INPUT_BUFF_SGL = InputBufferSglList();

InputBufferSglNode::InputBufferSglNode(const void* buffer, size_t size) :
    InputBufferSglHook(),
    m_buffer(buffer),
    m_size(size)
{
    // empty
}

void InputBufferSglNode::reset()
{
    m_buffer = nullptr;
    m_size = 0;
}

bool InputBufferSglNode::copy_buffer_from_list(InputBufferSglList &list, InputBufferSglIterator &iter, size_t &offset_in_node, const InputBufferSglIterator& end, uint8_t *target, size_t size)
{
    // implementation
}

int main() {
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I understand correctly, in this case the `InputBufferSglIterator` and `SglList` are now scoped under the class which is not what I want. So I'll need to re-define typedefs outside the class. and BTW, why is the `InputBufferSglNode` forward declaration ?  Thanks !

Comment: If you don't like the scope, just typedef it outside. If you insist, why don't you do as they say in the documentation I linked you to? And the forward declaration was your own :) I just made the minimal edit to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: The forward declaration in my original text is for the `InputBufferSglIterator` and `SglList` declarations so I guess it's just redundant... :) , anyway, I don't actually look for recursive list, maybe it was wrong to mention it but I referred to my recursive declarations only. I think Ill just drop the `typedef` for the method parameters and use them outside the class. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You never mentioned recursive. I did because that's the documentation section that mentions how to  avoid incomplete types during hook deduction (this was your problem). It's really not that difficult: either **[this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0f70d45810bc94e)** or **[this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e4b79fa1acef65e)** would do! Updating the answer so as to make it doubly clear.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]. I hope my edit explains it more clearly to you. My I draw your attention to this (since you've expressed your thanks twice now): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I have no idea why you keep pushing the recursive solution, it is not what I searched for and not what I asked for, I did however find in your solution a way to do what I want and this is what you wrote in bullet 2.

Comment: You know, @Sagilow. I'm **not** "pushing the recursive solution". It's not _my fault_ that the documentation describes the problem you have best in that particular section of the documentation. Also you "have found a way to do what I want" - yeah I hope you didn't miss the fact that I spelled out all the approaches in my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087278/error-incomplete-type-typename-named-in-nested-name-specifier/27088277#comment42692793_27088277) :)